# how to using a db function in where sentence via sequelize

Tags: node.js, database, orm, sequelize.js

I want to find an average value of this week and group by `dayofweek`, so I writen this sql, the sql is work well, but how can I achieve the same purpose via sequelize.

```
select dayofweek(datetime), avg(value) from Temperatures where week(datetime) = week(now()) group by dayofweek(datetime);
```

And here is my `Temperatures` table:

`| field    | type        |
|----------|-------------|
| uuid     | char(36)    |
| value    | float       |
| datetime | datetime    |`

I've read the document of sequelize, but it seems that there is no clear explanation of how to using a function after `where` sentence, the condition is a function but not a field.

I have tried under way, but it's not work

```
where: {
  [Sequelize.Op.eq]: [
    sequelize.fn('week', Temperature.sequelize.fn('now')),
    sequelize.fn('week', Temperature.sequelize.col('datetime')),
  ]
},
```

Thank your for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sequelize.fn` for that , something like this :

```
[sequelize.fn('dayofweek', sequelize.col('datetime')), 'datetime']
```

For more details **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html)**

Comment: thanks for you help!, the `where` is an object, I must using it with a [Sequelize.Op.and] operator.

Comment: Check this , you will get better idea : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50553568/sequelize-mysql-equivalent-orm-query?noredirect=1#comment88128583_50553568

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the following method works well

```
return Temperature.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [Temperature.sequelize.fn('dayofweek', Temperature.sequelize.col('datetime')), 'dayofweek'],
    [Temperature.sequelize.fn('AVG', Temperature.sequelize.col('value')), 'value'],
  ],
  where: sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('week', Temperature.sequelize.fn('now')), sequelize.fn('week', Temperature.sequelize.col('datetime'))),
  group: sequelize.fn('dayofweek', Temperature.sequelize.col('datetime')),
});
```

and if I need more conditional filters, just add an [Op.and] operator

```
return Temperature.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [Temperature.sequelize.fn('dayofweek', Temperature.sequelize.col('datetime')), 'dayofweek'],
    [Temperature.sequelize.fn('AVG', Temperature.sequelize.col('value')), 'value'],
  ],
  where: {
    [Sequelize.Op.and]: [
      sequelize.where(sequelize.fn('week', Temperature.sequelize.fn('now')), sequelize.fn('week', Temperature.sequelize.col('datetime'))),
    ]
  },
  group: sequelize.fn('dayofweek', Temperature.sequelize.col('datetime')),
});
```

here is the sql generated

```
SELECT dayofweek(`datetime`) AS `dayofweek`, AVG(`value`) AS `value` FROM `Temperatures` AS `Temperature` WHERE (week(now())=week(`datetime`)) GROUP BY dayofweek(`datetime`);
```